# Woocommerce: restrict a coupon code to specific tags

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I tried restricting a coupon code to specific tags using below code but somethig is off. It's not giving the 10% discount but rather the whole amount. It's not reading my if statement. Anyone has an idea? The code should only be applied if the product on cart has any of the defined tags below.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 'alter_shop_coupon_data', 100, 5 );
function alter_shop_coupon_data( $discount, $discounting_amount, $cart_item, $single, $instance ){
    // Loop through applied WC_Coupon objects
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_coupons() as $code => $coupon ) {
        if ( $coupon->is_type('percent') && $coupon->get_code() == 'makslid10' ) {
            $discount = $cart_item['data']->get_price() * $cart_item['quantity'];
 
            if( has_term( ['type_a1','type_a2','type_b'], 'product_tag', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ){
                $discount *= 0.1; // 10%
            }else{
                $discount *= 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return $discount;
}
```

Comment: `( $coupon->is_type('percent') && $coupon->get_code() == 'makslid10' )` Please verify the entered coupon matches the condition

Answer (score 0):

As I am checking, you should replace "product_tag" with "product_cat"

then you should also check your terms like:

$categories = wp_get_post_terms($cart_item['product_id'], 'product_cat');

echo $categories; exit;  and update accordingly on has_term condition.

One ore this you can also do the with loop and without loop also like this:

With Foreach Loop:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 'alter_shop_coupon_data', 20, 5 );
function alter_shop_coupon_data( $discount, $discounting_amount, $cart_item, $single, $coupon ){
    // Loop through applied WC_Coupon objects
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_coupons() as $code => $coupon ) {
        // check product turms
        //$categories = wp_get_post_terms($cart_item['product_id'], 'product_cat');
        if ( $coupon->is_type('percent') && $coupon->get_code() == 'makslid10' ) {
            $discount = $cart_item['data']->get_price() * $cart_item['quantity'];
            if( has_term( ['type_a1','type_a2','type_b'], 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ){
                $discount *= 0.1; // 10%
            }else{
                $discount *= 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return $discount;
}
```

Without foreach loop:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 'alter_shop_coupon_data', 20, 5 );
function alter_shop_coupon_data( $discount, $discounting_amount, $cart_item, $single, $coupon ){
    // check product turms
    //$categories = wp_get_post_terms($cart_item['product_id'], 'product_cat');
    if ( $coupon->is_type('percent') && $coupon->get_code() == 'makslid10' ) {
        if( has_term( ['type_a1','type_a2','type_b'], 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ){
            $discounting_amount *= 0.1; // 10%
        }else{
            $discounting_amount *= 0;
        }
    }
    return $discounting_amount;
}
```

It works for me.